# using autocomplete extender webservice in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, autocomplete

> This is code of webservice function in vb working fine

```
` Public Function GetProducts(ByVal prefixText As String, _
                                  ByVal count As Integer) As String()
        Dim SelectQry = "select * from employee where Ename like '" & prefixText & "%'"
        Dim Results As New ArrayList
        Try
            Using Command As New SqlCommand(SelectQry, Connection)
                Using Reader As SqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
                    Dim Counter As Integer
                    While Reader.Read
                        If (Counter = count) Then Exit While
                        Results.Add(Reader("Ename").ToString())
                        Counter += 1
                    End While
                End Using
                Dim ResultsArray(Results.Count - 1) As String
                ResultsArray = Results.ToArray(GetType(System.String))
                Return ResultsArray
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function`
```

> In Csharp i converted this vb coding..but not working.. i found some errors in converting string array into string.. near line resultsarray(results.count-1)

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string[] GetProducts(string prefixText,int count)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new

       SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\WebSite3\\App_Data\\Country.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

        con.Open();
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
        string strQuery = "select * from employee where Ename like '" + prefixText + "%'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int Counter;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (Counter == count)
                break;
            results.Add(dr["Ename"].ToString());
            Counter++;
        }
        string resultsarray;
        resultsarray(results .count -1);
        resultsarray =results.ToArray (GetType (System.String ));
        return resultsarray ;
}
```

> This is my Csharp coding here i found errors in resultarray..last 4 lines shows some errors like no overload for method'Gettype' and cannot implicitlyconvert type string to string[].

Comment: This is not a coding service, perhaps paste your own c# code with the specific error and you might get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like below :

```
string[] resultsArray = (string[])results.ToArray(typeof(System.String));
return resultsArray;
```

You can convert your code from Vb.Net to C# from below link :

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: cannot convert system.array to string[]